# Removing an HTML tag using Wicket

Tags: java, html, wicket, wicket-6

I am using wicket to develop a web application. Let's say I have the following HTML:

```
<div wicket:id="myDiv">
    ...content...
</div>
```

Now, that `div` is there because most of the time I want to write content inside it.
But what if there are cases where I want to **delete** that `div` (and its content) entirely? Is this possible in wicket?

I tried:

```
remove("myDiv");
```

in my Java backend, but it throws an exception:

```
Unexpected RuntimeException
Last cause: Unable to find a component with id 'myDiv' to remove
```

Any hints? I'm new to wicket and I find that it's incredibly difficult to find documentation on how to do even trivial things like this one...

Comment: I can wholeheartedly agree, that the biggest problem with Wicket is documentation. There is a reason we still use Struts2 instead :)

Comment: Yes, documentation was for a long time a problem. But this changed since there is the Wicket Guide: https://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/guide/7.x/guide/

Comment: What is the answer for this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution is adding an invisible `WebMarkupContainer`, then it won't render in the resulting HTML code:

```
add(WebMarkupContainer("myDiv").setVisible(false));
```

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks. Btw: do you know if there is a way to delete a tag that does NOT have a wicket:id, but just a regular html id?

Answer (score 5):

Either I don't understand the question or the answer by @meskobalazs is not correct.
By using `#setVisible(false)` the component and all its children won't be rendered, i.e. the inner content too.

Here are some solutions from me:
First is to use `<wicket:container wicket:id="..."`> instead of a `<div>`. This way it will be stripped off the final markup. See `IMarkupSettings.setStripWicketTags()`. By default there are not stripped off in DEV mode and stripped off in PROD mode. By usually I set this setting to `true` even in DEV mode because sometimes the `<wicket:xyz>` tags break CSS rules. And it is better to be more close to what runs at PRODUCTION.

Another way is to use `Component#setRenderBodyOnly()`. This way programmatically you say "I want only the content of the HTML element that is attached/used for this Component".

Comment: Removing the tag AND its content is the correct behavior I wanted, so the answer I accepted works correctly. I'll make it clearer in the question.